# character checking

Tags: java

if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u') {
        count++;

When i give the above statement it returns number of vowels in a word only if the given word is in lowercase (ie: input: friend output 2 vowels). I Want to know even if i give uppercase or mixed it should return number of vowels. How to do it?

Comment: +1 for your question inspired so many different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tests like:

```
Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'a'
```

instead.

Comment: @Sumithra: note that this will fail in a Turkish locale, because it has dotted and dotless i in both upper- and lowercase, so Character.toLowerCase('I') == 'ı' and Character.toUpperCase('i') == 'İ' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Answer (score 9):

One succint, simple way to do this without doing 10 comparisons:

```
if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c) != -1) { count++; }
```

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/strings/96string_examples/example_countVowels.html) there is a complete example - note they turn the string to lower case before checking the vowels.

You can also try with a case insensitive regular expression, example from http://www.shiffman.net/teaching/a2z/regex/:

```
String regex = "[aeiou]";               
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);   
int vowelcount = 0;
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);         // Create Matcher
while (m.find()) {
  //System.out.print(m.group());
  vowelcount++;
}
```

Comment: Another plus for the regular expression is that it can easily extracted into a separate method and can be reused for other patterns.

Comment: Hmmm as everyone knows, regexp is the *fastest* solution. I mean, development wise...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get upper or lowercase a simple approach seems to be the following:

Iterate over all the characters in the word and do the following test:

```
if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u'
|| c=='A' || c=='E' || c=='I' || c=='O' || c=='U') 
   { count++ };
```

Comment: +1 for using the "principle of minimal conceptual change". This is often overlooked in the rush to refactor but there are situations (such as fixing production issues for one) where it's vital, to ensure you don't introduce other problems. There's nothing quite so frowned upon as introducing a brand new bug in a production fix :-)

Comment: +1 to the comment for "principle of minimal conceptual change".. never knew this as a concept even though we use it often.

Answer (score 1):

I tell you one thing, if you give the out put in upper case then in your code accept given out put in lower case.

if string str='FRIEND'

handle str.Tolower();
Please try this I think your problem resoloved.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient solution, but perhaps the shortest? :)

```
int vowelCount = (inputString+" ").split("(?i)[aoeuiy]").length - 1
```

Btw, am I the only one counting 'y' as a wovel? ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u').contains(Character.toLowerCase(c))) {
   ...
}
```

I would also static final the list as well.

Comment: That list should be wrapped inside `Collections.unmodifiableList(..)` when declared as static final.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quite simple utility class :

```
public class Main {
    public static int countChars(String string, Character... characters) {
        return countChars(string, new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(characters)));
    }

    public static int countChars(String string, Set<Character> characters) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
            if(characters.contains(string.charAt(i))){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int countCharsIgnoreCase(String string, Character... characters) {
        return countCharsIgnoreCase(string, new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(characters)));
    }

    public static int countCharsIgnoreCase(String string, Set<Character> characters) {
        Set<Character> finalCharacters = new HashSet<Character>();
        for (Character character : characters) {
            finalCharacters.add(Character.toUpperCase(character));
            finalCharacters.add(Character.toLowerCase(character));
        }

        return countChars(string, finalCharacters);
    }
}
```

[code on ideone](http://ideone.com/qwzzX)

Answer (score 1):

Using Guava's [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
private final CharMatcher vowels = CharMatcher.anyOf("aeiouAEIOU");

...

// somewhere in your method:
if (vowels.matches(c)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see a `Set` yet :-(

```
  static Character charvowels[] = { 'A','I','U','E','O','a','i','u','e','o' };
  static Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(charvowels));
  ...
  public void countVowel(char c) {
    if (vowels.contains(c)) count++;
  }
```